# BeautifulSoup 4.0b markupMassage

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I installed BeautifulSoup 4.0b yesterday, and now I want to add a regex-replace pair that would be ran during the pre-parser stage.  In the documentation it says I can simply use the `markupMassage` parameter to `__init__` which assigns to `MARKUP_MASSAGE`, but it seems that 4.0b no longer has these attributes, despite not mentioning it in the README (unless I missed it?).

So my question is, is there a way to get this same functionality from BeautifulSoup 4.0b

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The README does (sort of) cover this issue, but it has to be inferred by reading between the lines of this section:

> = About Beautiful Soup 4 =
>
> This is a nearly-complete rewrite that removes Beautiful Soup's custom
>   HTML parser in favor of a system that lets you write a little glue
>   code and plug in any HTML or XML parser you want.
>
> Beautiful Soup 4.0 comes with glue code for four parsers:
>
> - Python's standard HTMLParser
> - lxml's HTML and XML parsers
> - html5lib's HTML parser
>
> HTMLParser is the default, but I recommend you install one of the
>   other parsers, or you'll have problems handling real-world markup.

The old custom parser was based on `SGMLParser` from the deprecated [sgmllib](http://docs.python.org/library/sgmllib.html#module-sgmllib) module (which was removed in Python 3), and the `markupMassage` functionality was mainly there to fix invalid markup that `SGMLParser` couldn't handle. So when the old custom parser went, the `markupMassage` functionality went with it.

Presumably, any functionality which is no longer provided by default will now have to be added by subclassing one of the new parsers.

So if `lxml` is installed, you would need to do something like this:

```
from bs4.builder import LXMLTreeBuilder

class Builder(LXMLTreeBuilder):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Builder, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def prepare_markup(self, *args, **kwargs):

        markup, user_enc, doc_enc = super(Builder, self).prepare_markup(*args, **kwargs)

        # do markup massaging ...

        return markup, user_enc, doc_enc

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, builder=Builder())
```